# extending firebase.database.Reference

Tags: firebase

in the old FB I added a helper function to get/set values as follows:

```
    // val() -> get(), resolve with value at ref
    // val(value) -> set(value), resolve with value
    // val(vals) -> update(vals), resolve with vals
    Firebase.prototype.val = function(vals) {
        let self=this;

        if (!vals) {
            return this.once('value').then(
                snapshot => {
                    if (typeof snapshot.val() === 'undefined' || snapshot.val() === null) throw 'INVALID_VALUE';
                    return snapshot.val();  
                }, 
                err => {
                    throw err;
                });
        }   

        let singleVal=(vals.constructor != Object); // is singleVal then vals is a single value

        if (singleVal ) return this.set(vals); // set single value

        if (!singleVal) return this.update(vals).then(() => vals); // update multiple values
    };
}
```

I could then do for example return ref.child(...).val();

This function does not run in V3.

How can I extend firebase in that way in V3 ?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution - I find this extension very handy

```
    // val() -> get(), resolve with value at ref, fails with error.code
    // val(value) -> set(value), resolve with value, fails with error.code
    // val(vals) -> update(vals), resolve with vals, fails with error.code

    firebase.database.Reference.prototype.val = function(vals) {
        let path=this.toString().substring(firebase.database().ref().toString().length-1);
        let valsAsString = (typeof vals==='string' ? vals : JSON.stringify(vals));

        if (!vals) {
            return this.once('value').then(
                snapshot => {
                    if (typeof snapshot.val() === 'undefined' || snapshot.val() === null) {
                        console.log('val('+path+') failed (null) ! '+error.message+' ('+error.code+')');
                        throw 'INVALID_VALUE';
                    }
                    return snapshot.val();  }, 
                error => {
                    console.log('val('+path+') failed ! '+error.message+' ('+error.code+')');
                    throw error.code;
                });
        }   

        let singleVal=(vals.constructor != Object); // is singleVal then vals is a single value

        if (singleVal ) return this.set(vals).then(  // set single value
            () => {
                return vals;
            }, error => {
                console.log('val('+path+','+valsAsString+') failed ! '+error.message+' ('+error.code+')');
                throw error.code;
            }
        );

        return this.update(vals).then( // update multiple values
            () => {
                return vals;
            }, error => {
                console.log('val('+path+','+valsAsString+') failed ! '+error.message+' ('+error.code+')');
                throw error.code;
            }
        );  
    };
}
```